# Open and Read Content of csv from URL android

Tags: android, csv, url

My code below is in attempt to open and read contents of a CSV file from URL. The CSV file contains lat and long which I plot on a Map. I have successfully executed the code while putting the CSV file into ASSETS. Now I just want to do the same but locate the file on a server. Any help would be appreciated. The snippet of code below runs, opens the map, but does not plot any points for me. The first two lines is what I have changed after moving the file to the server, the rest of the code is the same:

```
try {


            URL url = new URL(PATH);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));




        List<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        List<String> siteList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> siteRevList = new ArrayList<String>();


        String info = "";
        while ((info = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] line = info.split(",");

            latitude = Double.parseDouble(line[1]);
            longitude = Double.parseDouble(line[2]);
            siteName = String.valueOf(line[0]);
            siteRev = String.valueOf(line[3]);

            latLngList.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
            siteList.add(new String(siteName));
            siteRevList.add(new String(siteRev));
        }
```

}
            catch (Exception e) {

```
        }
```

Comment: A try without catch blocks? Show them and tell which get invoked. Show the errors and exceptions from the logcat too. Does your app crash?

Comment: I have  added the catch blocks which where in my code and not pasted here initially. I am very new to app development so I do not know how to find which get invoked. No, the app does not crash. It opens the Google Map but does not plot any of the markers.

Comment: Please format your code. You have nothing in that catch block. So how would you know if there was a catch?

Comment: You probably have a NetworkOnMainThreadException as all internet code has to be executed in a Thread or AsyncTask.

Comment: Thank you. I will setup and capture the exceptions being generated and update with details as soon as I have it.

Answer (score 0):

It must be throwing, 'NetworkOnMainThreadException'. It is caused because all the internet related tasks are to be performed either as an Async Task or in some other Thread.
So either Make an Async Task or put your internet code into another thread.